# Displaying data in a label after joining two tables in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, join, datagrid

I used this coding for joining two tables in **one datagrid**:

```
private void FillProjectsDataGrid()
{
    using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        var Join = (from a in DC.tblEmployeeLoginDetails
                    join b in DC.tblProjects
                    on a.LoginID equals b.ProjectID
                    where b.ProjectID != null
                    select new { Project = a, Employee = b }).ToList();

        dgViewProjects.ItemsSource = Join;               
    }
}
```

Now, in my datagrid's selection changed event I want to display the **ProjectName** (A column in my Projects table) in a label, but I do not know how to do this after I **joined** the two tables in my **datagrid**

Here is coding I used for my selection changed event in my datagrid:

```
private void dgViewProjects_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        tblProject tblP = DC.tblProjects.Single<tblProject>
            (i => i.ProjectID == dgViewProjects.SelectedIndex);
        lblProjectName.Content = tblP.ProjectName;
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> Additional information: Sequence contains no elements

I know the problem lies with the join, but I don't know how to fix this or how to access my joined items. Any help and advice would be amazing! Thank you :)

Comment: I am not sure why are you binding SelectedIndex to ProjectID, if selectedIndex is 0, you have ProjectID with 0? In join I guess its Project =b and Employee = a.

Comment: I cant see your join creating this problem, are there any matching values in the list where you call Single ?